# Releasing job in CUPS administration does not work

Tags: printing, cups, printer

In the CUPS administration interface on localhost:631 for a local USB printer, clicking on "Release job" button claims that the job is released, but when going back to the list of tasks, the job is still held. The status of the printer is "Idle, Accepting Jobs, Not Shared", nothing seems to be wrong, but I cannot print anything. I tried pausing-unpausing the printer, restarting CUPS, to no effect. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

OK, super embarrassing, but the printer's USB cable was unplugged, so of course it wasn't printing anything... (but no message on the CUPS admin interface made that clear). Plug the printer back in, and lo and behold, releasing jobs works again. :)